# Things are still loading after window onload has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, kendo-ui

hopefully someone can help me here. I'm returning a kendo listview of elements, each with an (unfortunately rather large) image coming from a web service.

I've added a loading spinner which is almost doing its job perfectly, except disappears often long before all the images are ready...

I'm using window onload and the jquery is very simple.

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    // When the page has loaded
    $("#loading").fadeOut(0);
    $("#search-results-page").fadeIn(600);
});
```

I would expect that the fadeIn could never happen until absolutely everything within it has fully loaded. In reality what is happening is that the spinner stays around long enough for almost everything on the page to arrive... including the basic outline of search-results-page... however the kendo listview item containing all the items and images, arrives a few seconds later.

It looks bad because the spinner goes away then the user has to wait a little longer for the content. Assuming this is because kendo listview is loaded after absolutely everything else on page has finished... including window onload?

Any advice or possible resolutions are welcome!

Cheers

Comment: The kendo listview loads with Javascript after the window has loaded. Due to the way it implements lazy loading there isn't an event that tells you it's finished - it has its own 'loading' spinner that you could maybe use.

Comment: I'll check that out... cheers! Seems really annoying. Or I guess the alternative is to use another listview

Answer (score 1):

Perform the `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` in your listview `dataBound` event handler.

```
$("#listview").kendoListView({
  … ,
  dataBound: function() {
    $("#loading").fadeOut(0);
    $("#search-results-page").fadeIn(600);
  },
  … ,
});
```

Can you show more of your code ?  If you have other components, you should look into [`jQuery.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/#jQuery-when-deferreds)